# How to conserve line breaks when saving text in a textarea in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I am saving text in a textarea in a mysql database, however line breaks aren't conserved.

The issue is, the text will be used in a tinyMCE editor, so nl2br won't work.

How can I conserve line breaks?

Comment: How exactly are you determining that "line breaks aren't conserved"? Unless you remove them, they should still be there in the database. Does this question perhaps boil down to how to put these line breaks back into tinyMCE?

Comment: The line breaks are probably conserved. You can use HTML in the default value that gets loaded into tinyMCE, so `nl2br` will work, try that.

Comment: @OliverNagy Not in xenForo. Also, I tried using nl2br for the textarea when editing, and they aren't added.

Answer (score 0):

New lines are always preserved. in database data should be saved with new line char `\n` in it